# Fastest way to look up in a list of Associations

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, associations

Given a list of associations `tab` where each association has keys `{"name", "a", "b"}`:

```
SeedRandom[2018]
n = 100;
names = RandomWord[n];
tab := Table[<|"name" -> names[[i]], "a" -> RandomReal[10], 
   "b" -> RandomReal[10]|>, {i, n}]
tab0 = tab
(* {<|"name" -> "nuke", "a" -> 4.41839, "b" -> 0.688305|>,
    <|"name" -> "iodine", "a" -> 6.61215, "b" -> 4.315|>,
    ... } *)
```

and a static list of the form `{"nameValue", "a"}` or `{"nameValue", "b"}`:

```
randomNames = RandomSample[names, n];
list = Table[{randomNames[[i]], RandomChoice[{"a", "b"}]}, {i, n}]
(* {{"waterspout", "a"}, {"encouraging", "a"}, {"saber", "b"},  ... } *)
```

what is the fastest way of extracting the values from `tab` based on `list`? For example if `list` contains `{"nuke","a"}` it should return `4.41839` but if it contains `{"nuke","b"}` it should return `0.688305`.

**Important additional information**

- Each name value in `tab` is exactly once in `list` (in particular, `list` and `tab` have the same length)
- The structure of `tab` and `names` is always the same, only the values for the keys `a` and `b` change (i.e. everything except the numerical values is static).  **The solution can have a high fixed cost, but after that should run as fast as possible on every new evaluation of `tab`.**

The following works but is quite slow (about 0.01 second):

```
Table[First[Select[tab0, #["name"] == list[[i, 1]] &, 1]][list[[i, 2]]], {i, n}]
(* {2.48345, 8.47655, 7.92796, 1.6882, ..., 3.65979} *)
```

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Because in my application `tab` comes from a stream and is updated at high frequency. But you can work on `tab0` if you want :). I want to process `tab` as fast as possible and wanted to highlight what changes (= the numerical values) and what is static.

Comment: You know, the code just would not verify until I realized that `tab` changed all the time... =D

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I'm making you think out of the box, hehe :). Thanks for you very efficient solution!

Comment: The order of the names in `tab` and `list` never change?

Comment: @CarlWoll That's right.

Comment: @anderstood, I think it would be a better idea to use Set rather than SetDelayed to compare answers since you have a random number gen in there. Your way you'll get different answers each time, which are harder to compare and also may affect timing slightly.

Comment: @alancalvitti That's why I added a `SeedRandom`. You can check that Carl's answer gives the same result as in the OP. But, I agree, that's a bit confusing that `tab` changes after every iteration. Btw thanks for your answer, I'll check it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function assumes that the order of the names in both `list` and `tab` don't change:

```
extractionFunction[list_, tab_] := Module[{rnk, a, b, s = Ordering[tab[[All, "name"]]]},
    rnk = Ordering @ Ordering[list];
    a = Pick[rnk, list[[All, 2]], "a"];
    b = Pick[rnk, list[[All, 2]], "b"];
    With[{sa=s[[a]], sb=s[[b]], r=PermutationList[FindPermutation[rnk,Join[a,b]], Length[list]]},
        Join[#[[sa, "a"]], #[[sb, "b"]]][[r]]&
    ]
]
```

For your example:

```
ef = extractionFunction[list, tab0]; //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.000185, Null}

Extracting the data:

```
ef[tab0] //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0000129, {2.48345, 8.47655, 7.92796, 1.6882, 1.86398, 3.81981, 3.66469, 
>     5.79178, 5.52018, 6.61215, 2.34137, 3.56046, 7.02237, 0.148731, 4.94333, 
>     9.47983, 3.25394, 5.08571, 7.15642, 0.000857735, 5.53244, 9.66373, 9.41381, 
>     3.08944, 5.71462, 2.2408, 9.44, 0.640177, 0.148516, 8.96909, 9.70023, 
>     0.507559, 1.89383, 0.600272, 6.77362, 6.62578, 9.28269, 6.40033, 0.689248, 
>     9.17103, 0.677636, 0.950572, 0.322821, 7.40765, 6.46661, 0.484517, 3.34366, 
>     0.298406, 4.88656, 6.84136, 2.39152, 1.72063, 9.26934, 0.195646, 0.695893, 
>     0.750353, 1.16114, 7.09758, 4.77873, 2.36114, 1.11616, 8.87156, 8.04428, 
>     8.39603, 5.66964, 0.688305, 3.89521, 5.58604, 6.29886, 0.751684, 9.65089, 
>     4.188, 5.72688, 6.12588, 5.17795, 4.25081, 6.48617, 8.07723, 9.69531, 
>     8.36877, 7.00888, 3.64206, 8.97193, 8.45415, 9.1015, 5.37611, 6.50624, 
>     1.12191, 3.89697, 3.40464, 8.4333, 0.406116, 4.25232, 0.994173, 7.95154, 
>     1.57853, 1.81928, 3.73122, 1.5254}}

**Update**

The OP requested a generalization where `list` need not have the same length as `tab`, with possibly duplicate names. As long as the names in `list` are all contained in `tab`, the following should work (I used some of @Henrik's ideas here):

```
extractionFunction[list_, tab_]:= Module[{assoc, rnk, grp},
    assoc = AssociationThread[tab[[All, "name"]], Range[Length[tab]]];
    grp = GroupBy[list, Last->First];
    rnk = Ordering @ Ordering[list];
    With[
        {
        a = Lookup[assoc, grp["a"]],
        b = Lookup[assoc, grp["b"]],
        r = PermutationList[
            FindPermutation[
                rnk,
                Join[
                    Pick[rnk, list[[All, 2]], "a"],
                    Pick[rnk, list[[All, 2]], "b"]
                ]
            ],
            Length[list]
        ]
        },
        Join[#[[a, "a"]], #[[b, "b"]]][[r]]&
    ]
]
```

As an example:

```
ef = extractionFunction[
    {{"waterspout", "a"}, {"encouraging", "b"}, {"waterspout", "b"}, {"encouraging", "b"}},
    tab0
]
```

> Join[#1[[{53}, "a"]], #1[[{10, 53, 10}, "b"]]][[{1, 2, 3, 4}]] &

Extracting the data:

```
ef[tab0]
```

> {2.48345, 8.47655, 8.52417, 8.47655}

Check:

```
Select[MatchQ["waterspout"|"encouraging"] @ #name&] @ tab0
```

> {<|"name" -> "encouraging", "a" -> 2.12, 
>     "b" -> 8.47655|>, <|"name" -> "waterspout", "a" -> 2.48345, 
>     "b" -> 8.52417|>}

Comment: Don't you loose the last item in `r = PermutationList@FindPermutation[rnk, Join[a, b]]`? `Length@ef[tab0]` returns `99`. Apart from that, incredible speed...

Comment: @anderstood I needed to use the 2-arg version of PermutationList.

Comment: I know I specifically asked for `list` and `tab` of the same length. Just asking: would this method be able to deal with larger `list`, e.g. containing _both_ `{"waterspout", "a"}` and `{"waterspout", "b"}`. It seems difficult because of `FindPermutation`.

Comment: @anderstood I think it should be possible with a little bit of work

Answer (score 6):

You can make a lookup table for the names and use `Extract`:

```
assoc = AssociationThread[tab0[[All, "name"]], Range[Length[tab0]]];
list1 = list;
list1[[All, 1]] = Lookup[assoc, list[[All, 1]]];
r = Extract[tab, list1]
```

Note that `assoc` can be reused and if `list` does not change, also `list1` can be recycled. For `n=100`, the extraction takes half a millisecond.

Answer (score 6):

```
ds = Dataset@<|#name -> <|"a" -> #a, "b" -> #b|> & /@ tab|>;
ds["nuke", "a"]
```

or using the list directly

```
ds[Sequence @@ {"nuke", "a"}]
```

Comment: Not as fast as Henrik's answer but very convenient, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
(tab // Query[GroupBy["name"], First]) // 
 Query[list // Query[All, Apply[Query]]]
```

> {8.06993, 6.16562, 4.24211,...,0.755269}

Or equivalently in Dataset form to contract the Queries (note `Dataset[list]` needs to be normalized anyway)

```
Dataset[tab][GroupBy["name"], First /* KeyDrop["name"]] [
 Normal@Dataset[list][All, Apply[Query]]]
```